# How to train Naive Bayesian Classifier for other documents using python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

There is a way to train data for already present datasets like movie reviews and gender classification using naive bayesian classifier.Is there any way to train some other documents using nltk python library?Thanks

Comment: it would be great to have some clarification on what you mean by "some other documents", please!

Comment: @amp to say,to classify ads from different types of advertisements.

Comment: I believe you've looked at http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch06.html. The examples used there are for gender and movie reviews, but if you have advertisement documents, you can certainly perform document classification with NLTK. Have you tried using that chapter as a starting point? You will need to first choose your features, define them, measure them and follow along the chapter. Is this the info you're looking for? If not, please clarify your question and tell us what you've tried so far!